API access to Agile Boards in Openproject
The collaboration plattform openproject offers the option to organize work packages in so-called agile boards. I am trying to interact (read/write) with these boards throught the openproject API by means of the python package pyopenproject. While I have been able to retrieve information about single work packages with the following code snippet, I cannot find any functionality allowing me to get information about their organization in these agile boards.
from pyopenproject.openproject import OpenProject

op = OpenProject(...)

ps = op.get_project_service()
projects = ps.find_all()
for p in projects:
    if p.name == 'project_name':
        proj = p

wp = ps.find_work_packages(proj)
wp_test = next(w for w in wp if w.id == 42)

Any hints on how to approach this problem or on potential additional ressources are highly appreciated.
I have skimmed through the documentation of the API and the pyopenproject package's code looking for anything resembling the agile board structure available in the browser-based GUI. The closest thing I found is the post object, which the documentation describes as "Represents a post in a board" but otherwise seem unrelated to the agile boards I am after.

Although the question is about a programming, it doesn't contain any code you have tried or any error messages that needs to be fixed, so it's probably the wrong Stack for this type of question.  If you get a start and have some code to post to your question, I would suggest doing it before a moderator closes it. (note - posting links or pics of code is not posting code you have tried to a question)
